# A conjecture on Schatten 1-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, tensor-products

I have a conjecture on Schatten 1-norm.

Before presenting the conjecture, let us first  specify the notions used here. A matrix $A$ is said to be a density operator if $A$ is positive semidefinite with $\textrm{tr}(A)=1$. The Schatten 1-norm of a matrix $A$ is $\|A\|_1:=\textrm{tr}\sqrt{A^{*}A}$.

My conjecture is: if $\|\rho_1\otimes\sigma_1-\rho_2\otimes\sigma_2\|_1=\|\rho_1-\rho_2\|_1$ and $\rho_1\rho_2\neq0$, i.e., the supports of $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are not orthogonal, then $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$, where $\rho_i$, $\sigma_i$, $i=1,2$ are density operators.

I know this conjecture holds for some special cases, but I do not know how to prove it in general. So can anyone help me?

Comment: For which special cases does this work?

Comment: For example, when $\textrm{rank}(\rho_i)=\textrm{rank}(\sigma_i)=1$, i.e., $\rho_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are pure states in terms of quantum mechanics, this conjecture holds.

Comment: Off the top of my head: it is notable that
$$
\rho_1 \otimes \sigma_1 - \rho_2 \otimes \sigma_2 = \\
\rho_1 \otimes \sigma_1 - \rho_1 \otimes \sigma_2 + 
\rho_1 \otimes \sigma_2 - \rho_2 \otimes \sigma_2 = \\
\rho_1\otimes (\sigma_1 - \sigma_2) + (\rho_1 - \rho_2)\otimes \sigma_2
$$

Comment: If you don't have an answer by tomorrow, I'll put a bounty on this question.

Comment: Thanks! I realize this conjecture may not hlod in general, although it hold in the case of pure states. The violation of this conjecture really surprises me, because this conjecute may agree with the Helstrom's theorem existing in the literature.of physics.

Comment: To see the failure of the conjecture, consider the density operators \begin{eqnarray} 
\rho_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}, \rho_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3}{4}&0\\0&\frac{1}{4}
\end{bmatrix}, \sigma_1=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix},\sigma_2=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}- \epsilon
\end{bmatrix},
\end{eqnarray} for some small enough $\epsilon$, e.g., $\epsilon=\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: excellent! Are you still looking for an answer, then?

Comment: I would like to say yes, because at the present I still feel confused and want to know the condition under which this conjecture holds.